# How to disable setCharacteristicNotification

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-stream

I am trying to build an app to get data from accelerometer through BLE.
As per the android developer site I am using function `setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)` to start data streaming from BLE device.
But when calling`setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, false)` to stop data streaming, it works sometime and sometime not.
I couldn't figure out what is going wrong, as I m doing everything according to information given in [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Can Anyone please give exact process how to stop data streaming i.e. how to successfully `setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, false)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `setCharacteristicNotification` method only tells the Bluetooth stack in Android if it should forward notifications/indications to your app. You also need to write the configuration to the Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor. See [Why does setCharacteristicNotification() not actually enable notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817005/why-does-setcharacteristicnotification-not-actually-enable-notifications), and use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor.html#DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE.